# reading geometries from a web service in python

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, json, rest

I have some code that connects to a gis server, esr rest service, and returns the geometries of the features on that layer. I can pick html, json, geojson, kmz, and pdf as returns and I can export the json and geojson to featureclasses using arcpy. What I am trying to do is, without arcpy or downloading the data, is use those geometries to identify if a series of input points are within any of the polygons. I figured the best way was to use geopandas.within but I cannot get geopandas to read the response from gis server as polygons. I tried a number of solutions from other stack resources and using the geopandas site but the errors indicate either the input is wrong or the format is unsupported. I think it has something to do with the fact I am using a return from a url.

```
import urllib.parse, urllib.request, geopandas, requests, json

testPTS = [[61.5620807,44.2004590],[60.4736610,42.1696271]] ## My Test points
url = "https://server.domain.com/server/rest/services/servicename/MapServer/0/query?" ## A Map Service Query URL
## Search Parameters
params = {'where': '1=1',
           'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon',
           'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects',
           'relationParam': '',
           'outFields': '*',
           'returnGeometry': 'true',
           'geometryPrecision':'',
           'outSR': '',
           'returnIdsOnly': 'false',
           'returnCountOnly': 'false',
           'orderByFields': '',
           'groupByFieldsForStatistics': '',
           'returnZ': 'false',
           'returnM': 'false',
           'returnDistinctValues': 'false',
           'f': 'geojson',
           }

encode_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode("utf-8")

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, encode_params)
json = response.read()

df = geopandas.read_file(str(response), driver = 'GeoJSON')
```

Comment: [`geopandas.read_file()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html) "returns a GeoDataFrame from a file or URL"-- you're feeding in a response string, which is neither of those things.  Try wrapping it in a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) object as the docs suggest.  If that fails, it may help to get answers if you post the actual response text and error traceback

Comment: I usually do post the response text, in this case I had tried several different minor adjustments all giving me different responses. I couldn't think of a good way to communicate them in reference to each approach I tried. Going back to the original esri code I added this with open("mapservice.json", "wb") as ms_json:
    ms_json.write(json)

df = geopandas.read_file('mapservice.json', driver = 'GeoJSON')
print(df)
The print at the end prints polygon geometries so I think what I was missing was that with open (mapservice.json)... creates a json in memory named mapservice for geopanadas.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
with open("mapservice.json", "wb") as ms_json:
ms_json.write(json)

polygons = geopandas.read_file('mapervices.json', driver = 'GeoJSON')
print(type(polygons))
```

Output is <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>

It isn't a whole lot different from the esri code I started with from https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000019645.

Replacing

```
df = geopandas.read_file(str(response), driver = 'GeoJSON')
```

with

```
with open("BWEZones.json", "wb") as ms_json:
ms_json.write(json)

zones = geopandas.read_file('BWEZones.json', driver = 'GeoJSON')
print(type(zones))
```

However, it creates files in the root of my python project and I want it to do the work in memory without saving files.

Comment: Pass in `StringIO(json_string)` instead of writing a file-- it will give back a "file-like object" but hold everything in memory

Comment: I created a new variable called jsonStr and added it in the original code by replacing the with open... like this
jsonStr = StringIO(json)
zones = geopandas.read_file(jsonStr, driver = 'GeoJSON')
print(type(zones))
error is     "jsonStr = StringIO(json)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes"

Comment: StringIO may not have worked but BytesIO seems to have, you got me moving in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I had to use BytesIO to pass the Geojson to geopandas

After getting your url response from the rest service

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, encode_params)
json = response.read()

jsonIO = BytesIO(json)

zones = geopandas.read_file(jsonIO, driver = 'GeoJSON')
print(type(zones))
```

The result is <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'> from the print type command. I am assuming this means geopandas read the geojson from the BytesIO and understands it.